# How to improve an algorithm to check if there is an element in the array that is equal to the difference between any other two elements in the array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, loops, sorting, time-complexity

I know that this is apparently a simple question. But I can't get a better approach to get better efficiency. Here's what I'm trying. It is very naive but I still can't get it correct.

1. Sort the array. (Divide and Conquer)
2. a) Select one element at a time 
   b) loop through all the remaining elements of the array (in a pair) to get 
      the difference between them to match the selected element.
3. Repeat step 2 till at least all the elements are found.
4. Store all the elements that match the condition.
5. Print the stored elements.

Comment: Share what you have tried out so far. This is not a free service, to do your job. We are here to help not to spoon feed.

Comment: can array have duplicates? negative numbers? What does "other two keys in the array mean"? Do you mean array indices or array elements?

Comment: @NAVIN I don't have to write code for the problem. I need solve it with just pseudo code or in plain English steps as I've written.

Comment: @ShanuGupta There are no duplicate numbers, no negatives, and by two other keys I do mean array elements.

Answer (score 5):

Condition `A[i] - A[j] = A[k]` is equal to `A[i]  = A[j] + A[k]`, so we can look for sum.

Sort the array.

For every element search if it is sum of two others using [two pointers approach](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-pointers-technique/) (increment lower index when sum is too small, decrement upper index when sum is too big)

Resulting complexity is quadratic

Answer (score 0):

Just out of interest, we can solve this problem in `O(n log n + m log m)` time, where `m` is the range, using a Fast Fourier Transform.

First sort the input. Now consider that each of the attainable distances between numbers can be achieved by subtracting one difference-prefix-sum from another. For example:

```
input:            1 3 7
diff-prefix-sums:  2 6
difference between 7 and 3 is 6 - 2
```

Now let's add the total (the rightmost prefix sum) to each side of the equation:

```
ps[r] - ps[l]       = D
ps[r] + (T - ps[l]) = D + T
```

Let's list the differences:

```
1 3 7
 2 4
```

and the prefix sums:

```
p     => 0 2 6
T - p => 6 4 0  // 6-0, 6-2, 6-6
```

We need to efficiently determine the counts of all the different achievable differences. This is akin to multiplying the polynomial with coefficients `[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]` by the polynomial with coefficients, `[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]` (we don't need the zero coefficient in the second set since it only generates degrees less than or equal to `T`), which we can accomplish in `m log m` time, where `m` is the degree, with a Fast Fourier Transform.

The resultant coefficients would be:

```
  1 0 0 0 1 0 1
* 
  1 0 1 0 0 0 0
=> 
  x^6 + x^2 + 1
*
  x^6 + x^4

= x^12 + x^10 + x^8 + 2x^6 + x^4 

=> 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

We discard counts of degrees lower than or equal to `T`, and display our ordered results:

```
1 * 12 = 1 * (T + 6) => 1 diffs of 6
1 * 10 = 1 * (T + 4) => 1 diffs of 4
1 *  8 = 1 * (T + 2) => 1 diffs of 2
```

If any of the coefficients, their negatives, or `T` are in our set of array elements, we have a match.